# Wagtail images working fine, documents not showing after upload

Tags: wagtail

We've got wagtail 2.0.1 set up to work with AWS S3 for media files, and that works great for images (uploads are sent to S3, the `/images` route shows all images in the image manager), it does not seem to work correctly for documents.

The settings we use:

```
# Storage for user generated files
if USE_S3:
  # Use S3 to store user files if the corresponding environment var is set
  DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'filebrowser_s3.storage.S3MediaStorage'
  AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = env('AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID')
  AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = env('AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY')
  AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME = env('AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME')
  AWS_S3_CUSTOM_DOMAIN = env('AWS_S3_CUSTOM_DOMAIN')
  AWS_LOCATION = env('AWS_LOCATION')

  MEDIA_URL = 'https://' + AWS_S3_CUSTOM_DOMAIN + '/'
  MEDIA_ROOT = ''

  FILEBROWSER_DIRECTORY = env('FILEBROWSER_DIRECTORY')

else:
  # Otherwise use the default filesystem storage
  MEDIA_ROOT = root('media/')
  MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

(note that `filebrowser_s3` is a small library that [extends the S3Boto3Storage class from the `s3boto3` library](https://github.com/Pomax/filebrowser_s3/blob/master/filebrowser_s3/storage.py))

We can upload documents, and these end up on S3 in the correct location, with the database getting a `file` record that points to the correct path to append to the S3 base location, but the /documents route shows "nothing":

[image]

Searching "works" in that it finds results, says there are X results, shows the category the results are in, but then shows nothing else:

[image]

Does the document app use a special wagtail constant that we need to set in addition to the media root/url constants, so that wagtail can show the document list with the associated edit/etc UI?

Answer (score 1):

This turned out to be caused by loading the document app, but not having the corresponding url patterns loaded. Running a duplicate of the production S3 buckets against a local wagtail copy with all debug settings turned on showed that there were no reverse rules for what were supposed to be the wagtail document routes, which showed our urls.py was grabbing the patterns from the document app, but did not actually load those patterns as part of the master urlpatterns list.

Comment: Congratulations on finding the issue! Could you mark your answer as the correct one, please?

Comment: can't, self-written answers have a 2 day delay before you can accept them.

Answer (score 0):

> Does the document app use a special wagtail constant that we need to set in addition to the media root/url constants, so that wagtail can show the document list with the associated edit/etc UI?

No, it doesn't. Could you please try with

`pip install django-storages`

and

`DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'storages.backends.s3boto3.S3Boto3Storage'`

? This is the standard approach for Django/Wagtail and S3.

If that works, there may be an issue with `filebrowser_s3`.

See also

- http://docs.wagtail.io/en/latest/advanced_topics/deploying.html#cloud-storage
- https://wagtail.io/blog/amazon-s3-for-media-files/

Comment: That didn't change things, although we were able to run things in debug mode and got a warning about there not being a reverse for `wagtaildocs_serve`, so checking to see if maybe there's something weird going on with the url patterns...